# On exponential formula for $C_0$ semigroups

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory, semigroups-of-operators

Let $T(t),t\geq 0$, be a $C_0$-semigroup on a Banach space $X$. If $A$ is the infinitesimal generator of $T(t),t\geq 0$, then
$$T(t)x=\lim_{n\infty}(I-\frac{t}{n}A)^{-n}x$$
for every $x \in X, t\geq  0$, and the limit is uniform on any bounded interval $[a,b]\subset [0,\infty)$. This is the exponential formula.

I wonder if one could affirm that the sequence $(I-\frac{t}{n}A)^{-n}$ converges in norm to $T(t)$ and the convergence is uniform on any bounded interval $[a,b]\subset [0,\infty)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an analytic semigroup (generated by a so-called [sectorial operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_semigroup)), then the answer is well-known and yes, even convergence rates are possible. This and generalizations were proved by many, see for example the summary and references in

[M. Crouzeix, S. Larsson, S. Piskarev, V. Thomée: The stability of rational approximations of analytic semigroups, BIT 33 (1993), 74-84](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01990345), Theorem 3.

In general it is possible to obtain convergence rates for "nice" initial values. A nice summary of the existing results and vast generalizations are available in this paper by [Alexander Gomilko and Yuri Tomilov](https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.4406).

ADDED: After discussion with Delio, let me mention that the result (in Hilbert spaces) is implicitely contained in

[H.  FUJITA  & A.  MIZUTANI,](https://doi.org/10.2969/jmsj/02840749)  "On  the  finite  element  method  for  parabolic  equations.  I;
Approximation  of  holomorphic  semi-groups,"  J.  Math.  Soc.  Japan,  v.  28,  1976,  pp.  749-771.

Answer (score 3):

In general, this is not true (think of the first derivative acting on $L^1(\mathbb R)$).

However, this might be true in some special cases: most notably, by the spectral theorem, if $A$ is a self-adjoint operator. Namely, in that case you can simultaneously diagonalize all resolvent operators, whose eigenvalues you explicitly know - so that you are essentially back to the scalar case. More generally, this is true for some (large) class of sectorial operators on Hilbert spaces, cf. Thm. 5.1 in *Operator-Norm Approximation of Semigroups by
Quasi-sectorial Contractions* by Cachia-Zagrebnov, JFA 2001. Their answer has been extended to general Banach spaces in *Some remarks on operator-norm convergence of the Trotter
product formula on Banach spaces* by Blunck, JFA 2002, see also Corollary 3.6 in *Euler’s Exponential Formula for Semigroups* by Cachia, Semigroup Forum 2004, if you are interested in an error estimate as well.

Comment: Delio, it is always true for analytic semigroups. See my answer I posted earlier.

Comment: Yes, András. I have not checked exactly, but I kind of remember that the results by Blunck and Zagrebnov even generalize those by Crouzeix & co. you have referred to.

Comment: sorry, I meant: by Blunck and *Cachia*.

Comment: They are about the Trotter product formula, not about Euler.

Comment: uh? Andras, I do not understand. Have you checked those articles? E.g., Corollary 3.6 in Cachia's paper is clearly about Euler's formula and has nothing to do with Trotter.

Btw, it is interesting to observe that for *Trotter*'s product formula you can have even better convergence, e.g., trace norm convergence (this has been proved by Cachia and Zagrebnov) if you are in a Hilbert space, and the same holds for other relevant convergent sequences (e.g., the Dyson-Phillips formula), but I have never seen trace class convergence for the Euler formula.

Comment: Cachia is about Euler for not $C_0$-semigroups.

Chachia and Zagrebnov and Blunck was more about rates of convergence for Trotter. 

The operator norm convergence of Euler for analytic semigroups was well-known in the 70's (Le Roux).

Comment: thanks, I did not know abouth that result by Le Roux. Are you aware of some similar results for $C_0$-groups or for cosine families?

Comment: Thank you for responding. Let me point out that P.loreti and A.Siconolfi (Semigoup approach for approximation of a control problem with unbounded dynamic) have shown convergence in norm uniformly for $C_0$-semigroups on the compact subsets of $(0,+\infty)$ when $X$ is a Hilbert space. I would like to have this propertie on  the compact subsets of $[0,+\infty)$.
N.B /I will be satisfied if $X$ is a Hilbert space. 


Comment: Wouldn't this imply norm continuity (and hence boundedness of the generator)?